# Bootstrap responsive: How to make columns in row move to only rows with small device?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Actually I am trying to build a form that has two rows on desktops.
Each of the rows has two columns.

This is the code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

When I try to open that form on a tablet or smartphone I want to display the columns as rows, too:

```
row1 with col1 and col2 shall become two rows.
row2 with col3 and col4 shall become two rows.
```

How do I set this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `col-md-6` class instead of `col-xs-6` as `md` targets medium sized screens and above. By default, Twitter Bootstrap is mobile first responsive framework, so it will occupy full width for smaller screens i.e. below `md` screen size.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">4</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: WoW! That's easy? Great! It solved my issue. I will mark your answer as solution as soon as possible.

Comment: No problem mate, take your time. Glad that was helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

here i set two class for multisize device.
here you can see two columns in large screen using col-lg-6 class.

and one column in col-md-12 medium screen and Xtra small device (col-xs-12)